# How to design a database with one-to-many and then many-to-many relationship?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm not very specialized with database design so much and I'm designing a database for the delivery company.

The situation is that we have two main actors, customer and truck driver. The customer will ask for a delivery and the truck driver must answer with an offer or a rate for that customer. The difficult part is, how to design a relationship between them, so the customer can request for a delivery and truck driver can give a good rate for that request. The customer should receive many offers from many drivers and drivers can receive many requests from other customers as well.

I thought about having **Customer**, **Truck Driver**, and **Request** as entities
and **Request_Driver** for the many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 1):

This is a many to many relationship. You will have a `Customer` table and a `TruckDriver` table.

You will also have a table called `Delivery` or similar which will manage the relationship between the two.

The delivery table would have the columns

```
CustomerID (foreign key, referencing the PK in the customer table)
DriverID (foreign key, referencing the PK in the driver table)
Rate
```

If one customer can recieve an offer from the same driver more than once, it may also be worth adding a column `DeliveryID` as the Primary Key on the table, otherwise you can use a composite key of `CustomerID, DriverID`

There may be other information you want to include in your delivery table such as date of offer and a flag as to whether the offer was accepted or not but that is not specified in the question.